# TensorFlow python loop "for" performance

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

I have a performance problem in python using the tensorflow.
The loop below is well delayed to run, is there a way to change or optimize this loop?

```
learning_rate_multiplier = tf.stack(
    [tf.tile(tf.slice(learning_rate_op, np.array([i]), np.array([1])), [dim])
            for i in range(m * n)])
```

Thanks

Comment: How is `learning_rate_op` defined?

Answer (score 2):

I revolved my problem, modifying the learning_rate_multiplier to

tf.reshape(self._learning_rate, [self._m * self._n, 1]